# Generic exception in Java for read-only

Tags: java, exception

Is there an unchecked generic exception in Java default package which would represent also the read-only exception situation ? If not, what is the best alternative exception to use?

My problem: The methods in API I use declares custom checked `ReadOnlyException`. I would like to handle this by re-throwing it (if this occurs it is coding error which should be guaranteed not to happen by my code if its correct) wrapped in some unchecked `RuntimeException` type. I do not want to write another `Exception` class for this.

Is there a good source of various `Exception` which come with Java code and in which situations they can be used (as I often stand before dilemma - writing custom `Exception` or using the existing one) ?

Comment: Well, you're not going to catch the exception anyway, so I'd just throw either a RuntimeException or IllegalStateException (maybe IllegalArgumentException, but I guess it's less appropriate here), with a clear exception message.

Comment: Take a look at the `Collections.unmodifyableXXXX` classes, they throw unchecked exceptions when they are modified.

Comment: Excellent list of Java exceptions [here](http://rymden.nu/exceptions.html).

Comment: When doing unchecked re-throw I used to do it with `RuntimeException` but my boss does not like it:) I cannot decide among `IllegalStateException`, `UnspportedOperationException` or `IllegalStateAccess`.

Answer (score 1):

I think [`UnsupportedOperationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) is the best fit if the data is truly read-only.

`IllegalStateException` if the data can switch from writeable to read-only.
(Initialization phase doesn't count if it doesn't "escape" the initializing code.)

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent list of Java exceptions [here](http://rymden.nu/exceptions.html). I've been using this page as a reference for years.

Perhaps an [EOFException](http://rymden.nu/exceptions.html#EOFException) would work for you.

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ FINALLY!! Someone actually checked out the link. :)

Comment: A funny non-answer, but a non-answer nonetheless, unfortunately.

Answer (score -2):

You could rethrow the exception blindly in case the caller can handle this exception

```
// throw a checked exception without the compiler knowing. 
Thread.currentThread().stop(checkedException);
```

This still allows a nested caller to catch the original exception, but without you having to declare the checked exception all the way.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon It is.  The problem is that you can't know where in another thread you are triggering a stop or what state it might be in.  If you "stop" the current thread it is the same as re-throwing the exception.

Comment: Thread.stop() has been declared inherently unsafe since Java 1.2, and shouldn't be recommended anywhere (there are rare exceptions, but this question doesn't fall into any exception category). Also, the resulting ThreadDeath exception does not fulfil the "is a standard exception for write attempts on read-only data" requirement.